# $.getJSON gives Undefined result (Razor web page and JSONresult)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, getjson, cascadingdropdown, jsonresult

I am just starting out on learning Razor. I have worked my way through 8 hours of a paid video tutorial and now I am attempting to develop a real world application with a lot of googling and side reading.

I have read many similar postings and tried many of the ideas but I am just banging my head against the wall.
This issue arises from attempting to create cascading drop downs (select client, update drop down list of contacts at client)
I have stripped out all the EF code and just gone back to a hand coded sample list of contacts.
I am not even attempting to rebuild the select list for the contact drop down in this example - I would just be happy if the alert message would display a result instead of "undefined"

Here is the JQuery code at the bottom of the razor page:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready
            (
                function ()
                {
                    $('#TblTrials_ClientId').change
                        (
                            function ()
                            {
                                $.getJSON
                                    (
                                        "?handler=Contacts", function (result)
                                        {
                                            $.each(result, function (i, item)
                                            {
                                                alert(item.contactname);
                                            });
                                        }
                                    );
                            }
                        );
                      
                }
            );


    </script>

    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

}
```

and here is the "OnGetContacts" handler in the corresponding cs pagemodel

```
public JsonResult OnGetContacts()
{
    List<clientcontact> clientcontacts = new List<clientcontact>{
           new clientcontact{ClientContactId = 1, ContactName = "Scott"},
           new clientcontact{ClientContactId = 2, ContactName = "Bill"}
           };
    
    JsonResult jsn = new JsonResult(clientcontacts);
    return jsn;
}
```

I have breakpointed just before the "return jsn" and jsn is a collection of two entries so the handler is definitely being called.
I am concerned that jsn looks more like the clientcontacts class rather than a JSON string but this probably down to my ignorance at this stage.

Here is my definition of the clientcontacts class

```
namespace TrialManagementSystem.Models
{
    public partial class clientcontact
    {
        public int ClientContactId { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I have tried a number of ideas such as item.ContactName instead of item.contactname
and result[i].ContactName and many other permutations

I would be very, very grateful for any suggestions.

Many thanks
Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your code:

```
 alert(item.contactname);
```

to

```
 alert(item.contactName);
```